# Toggling case on click of a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm having a text area, user can type in the text area, in start it will be lower  case, but once user click on the 'T(toggle)' button, what ever typing after that  will change to upper case previous one will be in lower case only . If again user click on the 'T(toggle button)' what ever type after that will appear in lower case and so on. I tried  but that was not successful.

```
<input type="button" name="toggleCase" id="toggleCase" value="T"  style="width:40px;" onclick="javascript:changeCase(this);" />
<textarea tabindex="1" cols="39" rows="2" onkeydown="checkTxtCase(this);"  name="titleText1">&nbsp;</textarea>
```

JS:

```
function checkTxtCase(elmObj) {
    setCursorToTextEnd(elmObj.id);
    var txtVal = elmObj.value;
    var txtLen = txtVal.length;

    prevSize = txtLen;
    var txtLast = txtVal.substring(txtLen - 1, txtLen);

    if (textCase == 'LOWER') {
        elmObj.value = txtVal.substring(0, txtLen - 1) + txtLast.toLowerCase();
    } else {
        elmObj.value = txtVal.substring(0, txtLen - 1) + txtLast.toUpperCase();
    }
    return true;
}


function setCursorToTextEnd(textControlID) {
    var text = document.getElementById(textControlID);
    if (text != null && text.value.length > 0) {
        if (text.createTextRange) {
            var FieldRange = text.createTextRange();
            FieldRange.moveStart('character', text.value.length);
            FieldRange.collapse();
            FieldRange.select();
        } else if (text.setSelectionRange) {
            var textLength = text.value.length;
            text.setSelectionRange(textLength, textLength);
        }
    }
}


var textCase = 'UPPER';
var prevSize = 0;

function changeCase() {
    document.getElementById('titleText1').focus();
    textCase = (textCase == 'LOWER') ? 'UPPER' : 'LOWER';
}
```

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: I tried here http://jsfiddle.net/KKX5G/

Comment: Why not just use the built in javascript toUpperCase function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var textCase = 'toLowerCase';
var pos = 0;

function changeCase() {
    var textarea = document.getElementsByName('titleText1')[0];
    pos      = textarea.value.length;
    textCase = (textCase == 'toUpperCase') ? 'toLowerCase' : 'toUpperCase';
    textarea.focus();
}

function checkTxtCase(elem) {
    var l = elem.value.substr(pos);
    elem.value = elem.value.substr(0, pos) + l[textCase]();
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/KKX5G/1/)

Comment: Thank you adeneo, what will happen to pos value if user deleted the text area content.

Comment: The pos value would still be the same, you can add a check, like I did in this [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/KKX5G/3/) to reset the pos value to zero. Also notice that since the only way to change the case is to reset the value of the textarea, the caret always ends up at the end after a key is pressed, and you could get the caret position and reset it to where it was, and a lot of other smaller issues etc. but this is the way to do it, and you'll just have to figure out how complicated you want to make it.

Comment: @RahulDesai - read the question, that's not how it's supposed to work. Type something, then click the button once, and type some more.

Comment: @adeneo Gotcha. Sorry, my bad.

Answer (score 0):

I have found out a plugin for you. Its really cool and it really works.

> http://jquerybyexample.blogspot.com/2011/12/jquery-plugin-for-uppercase-lowercase.html

This will help you

I have created a fiddle for you. Check It

http://jsfiddle.net/KKX5G/2/

```
$('#Txt').Setcase({caseValue : 'lower'});
```

Comment: Really Cool Plugin Elegant Coder +1

Comment: Thanks Elegant Coder, but i don't want to change the entire character case, only those characters after clicking the toggle button should change the case.

Comment: OK.. I was unaware of that. Hope this plugin may be useful for you at times... :)